# Cannot find symbol getActivity()?

Tags: android

I am learning android from Udacity's course on developing Android apps.

In that they show us how to develop weather app, but I am stuck in the code where we add the code for changing the temperature units.

My question is why can't i use **getActivity()** method in following code:

**Its in the first line of the very first function**.

```
class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String ,Void,String []>
{    
 public String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String unitType=sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_units_key),getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));
        if(unitType.equals(getString(R.string.pref_units_imperial)))
        {
            high=(high*1.8)+32;
            low=(low*1.8)+32;
        }
        else if(!unitType.equals(getString(R.string.pref_units_metric)))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"invalid unit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);
        String str= roundedHigh+"/"+roundedLow;
        return str;

    }
    @Override
    protected String [] doInBackground(String []params)

    {  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;
        String format="json";
        String units="metric";
        int numDays=7;
        try {

            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM="q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM="mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM="units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM="cnt";
            Uri builtUri=Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM,format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM,Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();
            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());         
            http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        /*RECEIVES THE STRING ARRAY FROM THE DOINBACKGROUND METHOD. THE RESULT IS BY DEFAULT RETURNED TO THE ONPOST EXECUTE
        * AND WE CAN ACCESS THE ARRAYLIST OF WEATHER WHICH POPULATES THE LISTVIEW BECAUSE WE HAVE MADE THAT STATIC.*/
        if (result != null) {
            MainActivityFragment.weather_adapter.clear();
            for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                MainActivityFragment.weather_adapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
            // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
        }
    }
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */


    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException

    {
        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";/*it will contain the weather data for seven days, it is an array*/
        /*every element of the list has a one element long array called weather which contains weather details of corresponding
        day.
         */
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";/*this will contain the weather description main title like clear

        /*The json object is created from the string which contains data in json format*/
        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.
        // We are doing this because we have to associate date with each forecast entry.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
        // julian day returns the number of days that have passed since the julian period.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.it contains the description of the
            /*weather for the corresponding day in the form of string*/
            /*weatherObject is the corresponding object of the ith day*/
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            /*OWM_DESCRIPTION contains the "main" description like clear*/
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".It contains the max and min temperatures
            // in double format with the keys mentioned OWM_MAX and OWM_MIN Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " +Math.round(high)+" / "+Math.round(low);

        }
        return resultStrs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because `getActivity()` is a Fragment class method: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())

Comment: You are inside a AsyncTask which which does not recognize getActivity(). Try to define a context at the top level activity.

in oncreate context = this. Then inside AsyncTask you can use context.getActivity();

Comment: @Joseph82 You are right. But when I put the same method in the Fragment class and call it using Fragment class object, it gives NullPointerException.

Comment: @SumitSahoo But when I put the same method in the Fragment class and call it using Fragment class object, it gives NullPointerException.

Comment: calling getActivity() inside a Fragment will always give null.

Comment: *calling getActivity() inside a Fragment will always give null.* <= yeah, sure, and the pigs fly

Comment: The main problem is that you copy & paste the code without understanding ... seems like originally the AsyncTask class was an inner class of some Fragment's derived class(so it could access fragment's methods) ... now, it seems, you move it to not nested class ... obviously, you should pass a reference to Activity or fragment to the asyctask instance ... but you should remeber that AsyncTask can finish it's job after fragment/activity is no longer valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Context and save in member variable of this class :

```
class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String ,Void,String []> {
private Context mContext;

public FetchWeatherTask(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

// use context as this.mContext everywhere you want
```

}

You should call above class using :

```
new FetchWeatherTask(context).execute(/* String parameters */);
```

Comment: Ok did what u asked. But same error still persists for the getString method of same function.

Comment: use `mContext.getString()` there

Comment: Because getString() is Context class method.. pls check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

You are inside a AsyncTask which which does not recognize getActivity(). Try to define a context at the top level activity. in `onCreate() :`

`context = this`.

Then inside **AsyncTask** you can use

`context.getActivity();`

Comment: getActivity() is for Activity if you are inside Fragment you can try  getSupportActivity()

Comment: getActivity is Fragment's method ... fragment is not context ... even if your `context` would be a fragment if construct `context = this` would possible then simple `getActivity()` would be possible too

Comment: what is `getSupportActivity()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String ,Void,String> 
{
 private Context mContext;
 String str1, str2, str3;

String finalStr="";

 public FetchWeatherTask(Context context) 
  { this.mContext = context;}

@Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
  {
      str1 = params[0];
      str2 = params[1];
      str3 = params[2];

    finalStr = str1 + str2 + str3;
    return finalStr;
  } 

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      Log.d("rs", result);
  } 

}
```

And in your activity:

```
new FetchWeatherTask(this).execute(new String[]{"a", "b","c"});
```